# Walk through all modules to find instances with a specific injection token

Tags: nestjs

How can I get all instances of injectables with the same injection token as it works with APP_INTERCEPTOR? I've been looking at sources, I do not understand it at all.

I will report what I have got.

```js
const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);
const moduleRef = app.get<ModuleRef>(ModuleRef);
const container = moduleRef.get(APP_INTERCEPTOR, { strict: false });
```

In my example, it does not work because It has to look only at the current module.

I looked over sources. I saw `find` a method, it can search and find multiple instances. While debugging I understand that the whole information is available in the object but I can not retrieve it in a type-safe way. While I was looking at the sources I did not find a way to retrieve it because everything is private and protected. All public methods do not have the required functionality.

There is a logical schema:

```
NestApplicationContext & AbstractInstanceResolver & 
  p r container: NestContainer
  p r instanceLinksHost: InstanceLinksHost;
    p r instanceLinks = new Map<InstanceToken, InstanceLink[]>();
```

Instance link that stores it.

```js
export interface InstanceLink<T = any> {
  token: InstanceToken;
  wrapperRef: InstanceWrapper<T>;
  collection: Map<any, InstanceWrapper>;
  moduleId: string;
}
```

It is possible to retrieve all modules from `container`, but it is private.
As I understand that all injectable instances are located in one map and multiple
instances per token are possible.

```js
instanceLinks = new Map<InstanceToken, InstanceLink[]>();
```

That is all, I can not find a way how to do it.
I am grateful for any tip.